# Recursive TreeView building (using Colors)

Tags: c#, excel, colors, treeview, treenode

I'm currently building a small C# app that enables the user to transform some data from Excel to another kind of view in another sheet.

In this data, there is a hierarchy: `Entity > Sector > Sub-Sector > Zone > ... > Room`
( "..." meaning there can be at maximum 3 additionnal unnamed steps)

[image: small view of what the data looks like]

As you can see, the data is based on colors, Orange being the Entity, ~Grey is the Sector, Blue the Sub-Sector and White the Room.

When the user loads the Excel file, it also loads the Worksheet names as Entities and adds them to the the TreeView; here's how:

```
private void BT_load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Tools.SelectExcelFile(OF_xls);
    try
    {
        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(LB_path.Text, 3, 1);

        Template_Metro test = new Template_Metro();
        foreach(Excel.Worksheet wSheet in xlWorkbook.Worksheets)
        {
            test.Entites.Add(new Entite(wSheet.Name));
        }
        foreach(Entite entite in test.Entites)
        {
            myTreeView.Nodes.Add(entite.Nom);
        }
     }
     catch(Exception x)
     {
        Tools.ErrorBox(x);
     }
}
```

After the load action, the user selects a Node in the TreeView (we'll use CoeurDePole as an example) and is prompted to select what is in the black box - on the picture.
When the user selects the data on Excel and clicks the `Create` Button, the tree should be updated with the corresponding hierarchy.

```
    //IN THE FORM CLASS
    private void BT_create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (myTreeView.SelectedNode != null)
        {
            Excel.Range selection = xlApp.Selection;
            Tools.AddNodes(selection, myTreeView);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sélectionnez une entité dans laquelle ajouter les données", "Erreur");
        }           
    }

    //IN THE STATIC TOOLS CLASS
    public static void AddNodes(Excel.Range selectedCells, 
                                TreeView treeView)
    {
        
        List<Color> colors = GetColors(selectedCells);
        
        try
        {
            /* 
            * This creates simple nodes within the selected node
            * foreach (Excel.Range cell in selection.Cells)
            * {
            *     treeView.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(((Excel.Range)cell).Value2.ToString());
            * }
            */
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Aucunes cellules sélectionnées!", "Erreur");
        }
    }

    public static List<Color> GetColors(Excel.Range selection)
    {
        List<Color> colors = new List<Color>();
        Color color;

        foreach (Excel.Range selectionCell in selection.Cells)
        {
            color = ColorTranslator.FromOle(Convert.ToInt32(selectionCell.Interior.Color));

            if (colors.Contains(color) == false)
            {
                colors.Add(color);
            }
        }
        
        return colors;
    }
```

Also I created simple classes corresponding to Entity, Sector ..., each containing a list of objects from the lower level hierarchy. (e.g. class Entity contains a list of Sectors).

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer, I don't necesserly require a C# answer but some algorithmic help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Elliott

Comment: There is no algorithm that can mimic a human brain.  The coloring for the most part is random.  I would start by fixing the worksheet so the coloring is consistent.  The rows with no color are the ones with Column A containing data.  So rows 13 and 15 I would add data in column A.

Comment: Column A doesn't always contain data unfortunatly ... The reason why i'm doing this with colors is that in every project, the excel files contain a fixed color code.

Comment: It's the client that fixes the data, as the room they have built contains (or does not) useful data

Comment: Then fix the person who created the excel file with inconsistent coloring.   Maybe a gun will help.

Comment: Still doesn't answer my problem though, on how to create treenode recursively depending on the color code used in this example :p

Comment: Then if every worksheet is the same create a table specifying the row and color.  There is no algorithm that can fix this issue.

Comment: I'll prove you wrong :)

Comment: The solve this problem my high school teacher gave out : Find the next two number in the following sequence : 14,23,28,33,42,51,59, _, _.  The answer is 68,77.  These are the subway stops on the NYC 3rd Ave. subway.